# Magento updated site theme is ready for testing!

Tags: discussion, design

As part of implementing the new unified themes across the network, we're gradually rolling out updated site themes for each site. As of today, we have enabled your updated site theme for testing.

If you can't see it right now, that's by design! This is a very early test implementation of your design and we need your help finding issues with it before we make it live for everyone permanently. So, keep in mind, there will be things that need fixing! We'll address those things as we can.

If you'd like to review it, here's how:

### How do I enable it?

[Click here](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences) and check the "Beta test new themes" option. This will turn on the new theme for all sites that have one in testing, including this one. *Here's [more info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314542/opt-in-to-beta-testing-new-themes) on how to opt in.* You can uncheck the box to revert to the older theme until the site is live for everyone. **Note, while turning it on is immediate, it will take a few minutes to revert to the old view - *but it will go through!***

### What type of feedback do we need?

#### On this post: Bugs related to this site's design elements

Please help us look for issues/bugs related to the theme design and how we have mapped the old theme to the new. This needs to be done within the [limits of the new unified theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes).

This could include colors of sections of the design or text, problems with JavaScript add-ons (if applicable), the logo or top banner appearance or other artwork.

You can also feel free to ask questions about the new layout if you're unsure how to navigate it.

#### On Meta Stack Exchange: General concerns about left nav or theming

There are some things that are definitely changing everywhere and can't really be adjusted on a per-site basis. A few of them include:

- Top banner is shorter in height, so some artwork has to be adjusted along with some logos.
- Left Navigation is active everywhere (but can be collapsed into a menu by visiting your site preferences - [instructions here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311237/284336)).
- Responsive layout is active, which lets the site adjust as browser widths change - no side scrolling (some pages haven't been updated, yet, though). For now, if you prefer the scrolling, you can disable this by clicking the "disable responsiveness" link in the footer.
- Many site elements including tags and voting arrows are standardized across the network.
- Link underlining is active. In an effort to make links more visible, they are now being underlined.

If you have concerns or issues regarding the left nav or the overall approach we are taking to theming, then [this Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness) is the right place for feedback.

As I mentioned earlier, there are some unique design elements like voting arrows and tags that are being standardized in this process. Keeping these custom elements makes our ability to maintain the sites too complex and, while we're very sad to see them go, we're in a difficult position of needing to make the site designs work together so that we can continue to address feature requests and bugs that will make your Q&A experience better. This is addressed in a [Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314799/why-we-initiated-the-latest-round-of-design-changes-and-the-role-of-meta) if you want more detail.

### What new themes?

If you're like, "What the heck are you talking about?", then you should read the Meta Stack Exchange post entitled [Rollout of new network site themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312365/rollout-of-new-network-site-themes) (and maybe the posts it links to for the full background). To follow along with the rollout of these new themes, go [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314979/rollout-of-responsive-design-site-themes-tracking-post).

### Thanks so much for your constructive feedback!

#### Oh, Who am I?

If you don't know me, I'm one of the [Community Managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do?s=1%7C141.4591) here at Stack Exchange. I'm here to listen to your input and convey it to our Design team for responses and fixes to bugs. I'll do my best to respond to your concerns and explain whether changes we've made are bugs that can be changed or if they're by design and why.

Comment: Who is down voter ??

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Leave it sometimes people are lazy Don't read post without any concern they do down vote. 
Take that as childish behaviour and move no :)

Comment: I am using this theme for last 2 hrs and I really like it, except default upvote and downvote button which I don't like

Comment: Look nice. But on landing page `https://magento.stackexchange.com/` ,does not have newest shorting

Comment: @AmitBera `https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions` you can get here

Comment: Buddy, I already know that. I am asking to add also landing page

Comment: @AmitBera: We're definitely looking into making changes on the homepage once the new theme is everywhere. It's too soon to know what those changes might be and it might not end up with the newest sorting. But the theme change makes it possible to tackle that project.

Comment: thanks @JonEricson for reply.

Comment: @JonEricson is anyone looking into reported issues, they are yet not acknowledged or rejected.

Comment: @VivekKumar: Yes, I'm passing them on to the designers and developers. I haven't gotten feedback on the two answers listed below. Probably we'll get back on them when they are fixed.

Comment: Thankyou @JonEricson, will report more issues if I happen to find them.

Answer (score 1):

Reputation in meta site's profile page seems a bit messed up perhaps need more margin on "top 3% this year" part.

.[image]

Note that it is happening with meta site and not the main site.

Comment: This problem is visible without the new theme, so this isn't an issue with the new theme. However, I will note it to see about fixing it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Text overlapping on Graph

Comment: This problem existed before the new theme. Even so I'll toss it on the list.

Answer (score 1):

Featured Questions - "Questions with an active bounty", don't seem to appear on the Meta testing site's menu.

eg. https://magento.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured

Comment: I don't believe meta sites have the featured tab because they don't have bounties. (Exception: Meta Stack Exchange.) Instead, they use the [featured tag](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) which is managed by moderators.

Answer (score -1):

This is not an bug in design,

its a feature request that you can add

[Mass Edit functionality](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2472/mass-edit-functionality/2473#2473)

Comment: Thank you downvoters, I really appreciate  your vote as well