# Mass Edit functionality

Tags: discussion, editing

Do we have mass edit functionality?

or is there way I can unlock that,

every morning when I search some of the spelling they appears with new post like

https://magento.stackexchange.com/search?q=magneto

https://magento.stackexchange.com/search?q=acheive

Is tough job to edit those post one by one,

can we have mass edit for correct Common spelling mistakes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no mass edit functionality available to the public.
I remember seeing a mass edit at one point when some domain names changed, but it was done by the community managers.
I remember I went on this path of changing magneto to magento but it was a painful job and I quit.

Comment: is there any way we can request for this feature??

Comment: not sure. And honestly this is very dangerous to allow it to the public.

Comment: yes you are right at your point

Comment: Hey Marius what is your opinion for Jon's solution, I think it will do a trick

Answer (score 11):

We don't have such a feature available for users. However, I have personally made the mistake of typing Magneto when writing about this site and I think we can help users avoid that mistake:

[image: Not a site for X-Men]

This is using a blacklist [warning](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2501/2622), which is not normally the right tool for spelling mistakes. However, I expect there will never be a legitimate question about Magneto and many people will slip up when typing. So I think it's a reasonable solution in this particular case. Please let me know if it causes any problems.

Comment: This should solve 99% of the problems. There is one drawback. I remember that at one point that there was an extension vendor called "Magneto'. I guess we'll have to find a way to go around its name if that comes up.

Comment: @Marius: Oh. I can make it a warning instead. Let me know if that's needed.

Comment: You can leave it like that for now. let's see if someone complains.

Comment: Did this also check for... [user's About Me](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2499/profile-is-not-getting-update-on-magento-stack-exchange)?

Comment: @AndrewT. Urg. Yep. I think I'll downgrade to a warning.

Comment: Question added with magneto https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262333/how-to-call-a-grid-file-in-form-xml-in-magento2

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala: Is it possible that is an error in the user's code?