# Profile is not getting update on Magento Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, profile-page

Today i tried to update and modify my profile pic and information. When i hit on save, The page is getting error.

[image]

Comment: Did you type "Magneto"?

Comment: @AndrewT. it's already in the profile.

Answer (score 5):

I [blocked "Magneto"](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2475/2622) on the site to prevent a common misspelling. On further consideration, this should be a warning instead. Afterall, I can easily imagine an X-Men fan wanting to write about their favorite villian in their "About Me" section. Or, they might want to use that string as their username.

So you should be able to save your changes now. And people will still get warned that they are making a common mistake. Sorry for the trouble. As always, please let me know if this is causing other problems.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the update. I have modified and saved successfully my profile. Thanks

Comment: Good to know such ability exists for CM, can be really useful. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You have this in the About Me section:

> Can work on the Theme customization & Implementation and extension customization on **Magneto** 1 &2

You added that back when the system didn't check for it  yet, but now it does and block it with a humorous message, probably after countless users made that mistake.

Change the "[Magneto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magneto_(comics))" to "Magento" and all should be fine. :)

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the update. I have just checked and cleared the reason for the issue.