# getting an Unknown Warning (This is a site for Magento, not an X-Men character. ;-))

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

i am Trying to ask question in Magento 2 I am Getting a Warning

**Question**

Not Getting Values of selected Custom Options On Add to Wishlist In Magneto 2

**Warning**

This is a site for Magento, not an X-Men character. ;-)

I looks Bit Funny But i still want to know what is this

Comment: cc : [Mass Edit functionality](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2472/mass-edit-functionality)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting this because your are typing in "maGNeto" instead of "maGEnto"

[image]